# GoBuffalo and Authboss (authentication system) integration

Tags: authentication, go, buffalo

I'm trying to use `authboss` (https://github.com/volatiletech/authboss) with `GoBuffalo` (https://github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo).

*I'm still learning Go and I think this is a good exercise.*

I created a new GoBuffalo app, you can find it here: https://github.com/frederikhors/buffalo-authboss-sample

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE**

- `git clone https://github.com/frederikhors/buffalo-authboss-sample`
- `cd` in project root
- `go get -u -v github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo/buffalo`
- `go mod tidy`
- `buffalo dev`

As you can see the new buffalo app is minimal (all the features are commented).

I copied a very small set of instructions from this sample repo: https://github.com/volatiletech/authboss-sample

The app starts but I can't open http://localhost:3000/auth/login (404 page not found).

Using `app.Mount("/auth", http.StripPrefix("/auth", ab.Config.Core.Router))` creates routes as you can see in dashboard (http://localhost:3000/) or in the screen below.

**Buffalo routes**:

```
GET     /auth/{path:.+}/    authPath    github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo.WrapHandler.func1
PUT     /auth/{path:.+}/    authPath    github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo.WrapHandler.func1
PATCH   /auth/{path:.+}/    authPath    github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo.WrapHandler.func1
HEAD    /auth/{path:.+}/    authPath    github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo.WrapHandler.func1
OPTIONS /auth/{path:.+}/    authPath    github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo.WrapHandler.func1
DELETE  /auth/{path:.+}/    authPath    github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo.WrapHandler.func1
POST    /auth/{path:.+}/    authPath    github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo.WrapHandler.func1
```

**I can't understand how to tell Buffalo to render authboss views for that routes.**